# How to retrieve the data between two date in SQL Server R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to retrieve the date between two date insql server R2 version. Here I have the following Table CategoryProductStoreMapping

```
{CategoryID------ProductID------Qty-------date-----
 ---  3  --------  12  -------- 7 ------ 2013-01-05 
 ---  6  --------  22  -------- 14 ----- 2013-01-06  
 ---  8  --------  11  -------- 9 ------ 2013-01-07 }
```

I want to retrieve the data which are stored in Date between '2013-01-05' and '2013-01-07'
I have tried in many ways like

```
 {SELECT *
  FROM CategoryProductStoreMapping as RL
  where 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), RL.[Date],103) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),'2013-01-05',103)
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),'2013-01-07',103)}
```

I have also tried the following statement to retrieve the same:

```
 { SELECT *
  FROM CategoryProductStoreMapping as RL 
  where RL.[Date]>='2013-01-05' and  RL.[Date]<='2013-01-07'}
```

I also tried this:

```
 { SELECT *
  FROM CategoryProductStoreMapping as RL 
  where RL.[Date] between '2013-01-05' and '2013-01-07'}
```

In place of '' I have tried ## to define the SQL; it is date but still the data is not retrieved. By doing so I am only able to retrieve the column name but not the data.

Comment: What datatype is date column in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check bellow link might help you,

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/220dc/2)